# How to write $x= \sqrt{n^2+2}$ as a continued fraction and prove that x is irrational?

Tags: functions, fractions, continued-fractions, birational-geometry

I have to write $x= \sqrt{n^2+2}$ as a continued fraction, where $n \in N^*$.

I tried something like this: 
$$n< \sqrt{n^2+2}<n+1 \text{ so } [a_{0}]=n\\ x_1= \frac{1}{x-a_0}=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{n^2+2}+n), [a_1]=n $$

but for $x_2$ I obtained $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}$. From here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you mean *continued* fraction?

Comment: I don't really know English terms, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 6):

Consider instead $y=x-n$ then we have
\begin{align}
y
&=\sqrt{n^2+2}-n\\
&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{n^2+2}-n\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+2}+n\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+2}+n}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{n^2+2}+n}\\
&=\frac1{n+\frac{y}2}\\
&=\frac1{n+\frac{1/(n+y/2)}2}\\
&=\frac1{n+\frac1{2n+y}}\\
\end{align}
Applying this final recurrence should give a continued fraction representation of 
$$y=[0;\overline{n,2n}]$$
and so we have
$$x=[n;\overline{n,2n}]$$
$x$ is then irrational because any rational number has a finite continued fraction representation.